# Getting a list of dynamic Components using Core Service

Tags: 2011, core-service

Is it possible, to get a list of Components which are getting published dynamically using the SDL Tridion Core Service (or getting a list of Component Templates which can be published dynamically).

When using `GetListXML` I have been able to get a list of all Component Templates, but in the XML I can't see if they are "dynamic". The XML node for a template looks like this:

```xml
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:80-413-32" Title="Sample Compound Component Template" Type="32"
     Modified="2008-08-22T00:52:33" FromPub="01 Global Parent" IsNew="false" 
     Icon="T32L0P0S4" SubType="4" IsPublished="false" Lock="0" IsShared="true" 
     IsLocalized="false" Trustee="tcm:0-11-65552" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

As per the Core Service API Reference Guide available in the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_496D5B802DC840FDBC809A24257C2B0F) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)), use `ComponentTemplateData.IsRepositoryPublishable` Property, which gets or sets whether the Component Template renders "dynamic" Component Presentations."

Comment: Thanks Nickoli, But my issue was that i want to get all the dynamic component templates in the CMS for a publication. Using the above approach , i will have to get all the component templates and then check for individual templates .Is there a way using GetListXML where i can get all the component templates in xml and then filter them using an attribute.The XML node that i got for component template doesnot contain any attribute related to dynamic component.

Comment: The xml node for template                                         <tcm:Item ID="tcm:80-413-32" Title="Sample Compound Component Template" Type="32" Modified="2008-08-22T00:52:33" FromPub="01 Global Parent" IsNew="false" Icon="T32L0P0S4" SubType="4" IsPublished="false" Lock="0" IsShared="true" IsLocalized="false" Trustee="tcm:0-11-65552" />

Comment: I don't believe that you can do it all in one call.  You'll need to get all CTs and filter them out.

Comment: The performance impact here is not expected to be severe because the amount of CTs in the system should not ampount in a large number of loop iterations.